# Travel Requirements for Spain/Schengen

Tags: paperwork, international-travel, schengen-visas, applications, spain

I intend to travel to Spain using Schengen visa. From my research, I
found out I must show I have EU77.07/day available during my stay, I must
have a return ticket and I must have insurance coverage during my stay.
Is this correct?

Moreover, the return ticket requirement is clear, but I was not able to find
anything substantial on how I can prove the availability of EU77.07 per 
day. Do I show a copy of my account balance for this total?

For the insurance coverage: I was not able to find anything that seemed
reliable. Can anyone suggest on any plan or the conditions that must be met
for the required coverage?

EDIT 12/17/19: I am in the list of countries that do not require a visa application. Sorry for not being clear.  And I don't intend to go anywhere outside of Spain while there. Thank you all for your comments. I was in Spain when I wrote my profile, thought would stay there but things changed and I am not there anymore.

EDIT2: Thank you all, thanks for your comments, sorry for not being clear.
According to my research, while not needing a visa per se. My doubts are strictly about the specs on the requirements  to certify my ability to support myself to the tune of $EU77.07 /Day and show health coverage: How do I certify I have the required funding and what type of specs are need for the health certificate?

Comment: Where are you applying from? The VFS Global site for your location is usually a good place to find such information.

Comment: @Traveller: From what I understand, Schengen is automatic, i.e., no need to apply for visa except for a few countries neither of which I am from.

Comment: I don’t understand what you mean by ‘Schengen is automatic’? Do you mean you are eligible to enter visa-free by virtue of your citizenship (you don’t say what that is)? If so, you should edit your question - as it stands it reads as if you’ll be applying for a visa

Comment: Your user profile says you are already in Spain?

Comment: So you are from the list of visa-free countries? If so, you will be asked on entry about your travel plans, *possibly* including the availability of funds and return ticket. You are not expected to have it all as cash, but a normal traveler would have *some* cash at hand.

Comment: @MichaelHampton : Sorry for the confusion, I was in Spain and thought I would be staying there but things changed and I am not there anymore.

Comment: @o.m: Yes, I am, I am just looking for information to satisfy the requirements to enter the country. Please see my reply above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the comments, it is apparent you are from an Annex II country.  (Annex II lists countries whose citizens are exempt from the short-stay visa requirement in the Schengen area.)

Often, citizens of these countries are not asked to prove that they can support themselves, but it is possible, and you should be prepared to do so.  You do not need to have the required amount in cash; it's 2019.  Or maybe 2020 by the time you get there.  Everyone knows that people can spend money without having cash in their pockets.

You're probably aware that you should nonetheless have a good chunk of cash as a buffer in case there is a problem with your foreign bank cards.  This has happened to me several times.  But you don't need to carry thousands of euros.

If you're still worried about what might happen if you are challenged, consider bringing a recent bank statement to show how much money you have available to spend.  Visa applications sometimes ask for the last three months of bank statements, to show that your spending patterns are consistent.

On the other hand, people with too much documentation are sometimes suspected of intending to apply for a job or a long-term lease, so if you do bring three months of bank statements, be prepared to have extra evidence to show your intention to leave before you use up your 90 days.

Health insurance is a requirement for visa applications, but it is not required by the [Schengen Borders Code](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:02016R0399-20190611) for visa-free entry.

A return ticket is not in fact required.  If you don't have a ticket out, however, you need a credible plan for your departure and the means to purchase the ticket.  That would of course be in addition to the €77.07 a day for your basic expenses.  Similarly, if you mention plans that involve spending a lot of money, those amounts would be reckoned on top of the basic expenses.

But, to reiterate the second paragraph of this answer, the likelihood that the immigration officer will get into this level of detail is very remote indeed.